# Search code history for closest matching version based on content

Tags: version-control

I have a file that was forked from a project at an unknown moment in the past. I want to identify as closely as possible the moment of that fork. The file has been changed since the fork-moment.

Winmerge highlights about about 20% of the lines, with about half of those being just a few characters within the line, a path change or inline function turned into a variable or function call for instance. (20% after ignoring whitespace change and enabling moved-block detection that is, closer to ~40% without that.)

I don't have to worry about branches, the original version control system was CVS. (I don't have access to the CVS file system). I have a git imported version with tags corresponding to the CVS commits, and could generate the same with Mercurial for little effort if need be.

I don't care about matching the specific CSV commit date/time/number/whatever. The goal is to identify when the content of new file started drifting, and step forward through the revision history, cherry picking what to merge to the forked file.

For this project I *could* brute force it, there only a dozen or so revisions where the fork has mostly likely occurred and the file is less than 500 lines. However it's not hard to imagine a scenario where this is not feasible and I'm curious about what an elegant solution might be.

How would you go about solving this?

Answer (score 0):

"Brute force" sounds as if you were contemplating testing all revisions. Normally one would use a binary search.  To decide if it was a good match, I'd normally use just the numbers from diffstat (since you say there are post-fork changes).  Accounting for block-moves complicates things, though.